# collecting nullable fields in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to collect the nullable fields from the db, is there any script which can help me ?
It is important to know which fields must be checked against null during the programming.

Thanks in advance.

Cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
where constraint_type = 'C'
```

or, more precisely:

```
select owner, constraint_name, table_name, column_name 
from all_cons_columns
```

**UPDATE**:To get nullable columns:

```
SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS
MINUS
SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
from all_cons_columns
```

Comment: it gives the not nullable fields, but it is much better than nothing, thanks

Comment: have you checked the second query against my question ? but it is also helpful, since im new to Oracle

Comment: ok, I've put a query with all column minus not nullable columns :)

Answer (score 3):

```
select owner, table_name, column_name, data_type 
from   all_tab_cols 
where  nullable = 'Y';
```